# How can I create the dynamic field in the store?

Tags: extjs4

How can I create the dynamic field in the store?
because of if my data resource has 100 fields,I have to create 100 fields in the store property 'fields' or create the model within 100 fields.
Do I have good way to dynamic get the fields from Json?

Comment: Dynamic field? Did you mean dynamically load the fields first, then create the store?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly how your JSON is structured, I'll assume that each record has 100 fields with no nested data. Here's some basic pseudo-code you can start with:

```
var json = getJsonResponse();
var meta = json[0];  // Get a sample record
var fields = [];
for (field in meta) {
    if (typeof meta[field] !== 'function') {
        fields.push({name: field, type: "auto"});
    }
}
```

Assuming the first record in your JSON is representative of the whole, this should help dynamically declare your fields. You'll need to tweak the example to fit your particular data though.